# Jquery Uploadify getting filename with dots v2.1.0

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of my old project I am using Jquery Uploadify version v2.1.0. Following is the code to initialize

```
$("#uploadify").uploadify({
            'uploader': 'jScript/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'uploadFile.aspx',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.gif',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'queueID': 'fileQueue',
            'auto': true,
            'multi': true,
            'sizeLimit': 10485760, // 1MB = 1024*1024*10 bytes
            'onSelect': function (event, ID, fileObj) {
                uploadType = 'referenceImgs';
            }
        });
```

One another function we are using that fire automatically after upload complete.

```
function syncCallOnComplete(FileName){}
```

If we upload file with large file name suppose **New_Filename_12182014114951-Hydrangeas-125225235223.jpg**, we are getting file name like **New_Filename_12182014114951-Hydran...** which is incorrect.

But on server side in handler it is correct no issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try check filename on 'onUploadSuccess'.

Or try update to newer version.